# How to change the project 'Unreal Studio' Into a C++ project in Unreal Engine 4.20

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I am afraid I am posting my problem in the wrong place, if so then please excuse me for that and would appreciate it if you can suggest another forum for my question apart from Unreal forum as I haven't received anything for almost a month.
I am trying to import a model from 3d Max to Unreal engine so I can use it later on with AirSim.

firstly, I have converted my 3d Max model using Datasmith, a plugin to import 3d max model into Unreal, according to this video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1GH7QDYQXeI),  and everything went ok.

secondly,  this tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1oY8Qu5maQQ) is from AirSim official staff that shows how to download a free model from Unreal Library and merges it into a blank C++ project in Unreal so that it would be ready to suit AirSim. The free to download sample environment was ''LandscapeMountains''.

the problem is, video 1 doesn't show how to save the imported model that matches the ''LandscapeMountains'' project format so I can follow video 2 from that point onward to use it in AirSim. To clarify:

project folder of ''LandscapeMountains'' contains many essential elements such as the DerivedDataCache, config, and Content.

the imported model firstly doesn't have  DerivedDataCache folder.
In addition, the Imported model  Config files are by no means close to ''LandscapeMountains'' config files. Moreover, the Imported model contents folder contains Developers, Collections, and exported_model folders plus a .umap file of the exported model. whereas ''LandscapeMountains'' content folder has only two folders: Maps and Assets folders. all these details are shown in images1,2,3 and 4.
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvLO7.jpg)  [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUVKi.jpg) [image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ol2ki.jpg) [image4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zijB.jpg)

apparently, I don't know how the ''LandscapeMountains'' has been saved to look like this format and my question now is what is the type of this format and how can I save my imported model to be like that.

I think that its a basic thing but I don't have the knowledge to find out how and I hope someone can help to overcome this issue.

regards

PS, I have posted the same issue to Unreal forums and no luck with a reply

Comment: what is inside of assets folder?

Comment: There are 7 folders: Audio, Blueprints, Landscape, Materials, Meshes, ParticleEffects and Textures.